# Indeterminate checkbox in React JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I render an indeterminate checkbox via JSX?

Here's what I've tried:

```
function ICB({what}) {
  return <input type="checkbox"
                checked={what === "checked"} 
                indeterminate={what === "indeterminate"} />;
}
```

However, `indeterminate` is not an attribute on the `HTMLElement`, but a **property**. How do I set properties from React / JSX?

---

***Solution***:

As most of the answers below use `findDOMNode` or `string` refs, both of which are no longer considered good practice in React, I've written a more modern implementation:

```js
function ICB() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);
  const indetSetter = React.useCallback(el => {
    if (el && state === 2) {
      el.indeterminate = true;
    }
  }, [state]);
  const advance = () => setState(prev => (prev + 1) % 3);
  
  return <input type="checkbox"
                checked={state === 1}
                ref={indetSetter}
                onClick={advance} />;
}
                
ReactDOM.render(<ICB />, document.getElementById("out"));
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello. I tried using your solution for my problem (nested checkboxes), but it keeps returning null. Can you help with the solution?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can also use the ref function directly:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <label>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      ref={input => {
        if (input) {
          input.indeterminate = true;
        }
      }}
    />
    {' '}
    Un test
  </label>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Who downvoted this answer?! This is by far the easiest and most straight forward solution.

Comment: Is it possible to reference itself if passed an `indeterminate` prop in the JSX? It doesn't seem to work when I try. Something like... `if (input && this.input.props.indeterminate)`

Answer (score 13):

I would probably create a composite component that encapsulates the necessary hooks to set or unset the checkbox's `indeterminate` property. It looks like you're using ES2015 syntax, so I'll use some of those features here.

```
class IndeterminateCheckbox extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.indeterminate === true) {
      this._setIndeterminate(true);
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(previousProps) {
    if (previousProps.indeterminate !== this.props.indeterminate) {
      this._setIndeterminate(this.props.indeterminate);
    }
  }

  _setIndeterminate(indeterminate) {
    const node = React.findDOMNode(this);
    node.indeterminate = indeterminate;
  }

  render() {
    const { indeterminate, type, ...props } = this.props;
    return <input type="checkbox" {...props} />;
  }
}

// elsewhere

render() {
  return <IndeterminateCheckbox
           checked={this.props.state === "checked"} 
           indeterminate={this.props.state === "indeterminate"} />
}
```

Working example: https://jsbin.com/hudemu/edit?js,output

Comment: Thanks. Now I think `indeterminate` should have been an attribute in HTML, but this is a solid solution. I'll accept @manji 's answer as they were first

Comment: Note that `React.findDOMNode` is deprecated as of 0.14. Use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` from the `react-dom` package instead.

Comment: It seems that findDOMNode is deprecated now.

Comment: @LushaLi Yes, this post is pretty old — nowadays you'd use a `ref` to find the DOM node

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `componentDidMount` step (which is invoked after the initial rendering) to set that property:

```
componentDidMount() {
    React.findDOMNode(this).indeterminate = this.props.state === "indeterminate";
}
```

If you want that property to be updated with subsequent renders, do the same thing in `componentDidUpdate` also.

Comment: That would not react to new props, I guess I could use `componentDidUpdate`. But that's not run on the initial render... Is there an elegant way?

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` is not called on first render, `componentDidMount` is not called on subsequent renders. You have to use both.

Comment: It looks like React allows custom `data-` attributes, but nothing else: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html#custom-html-attributes

Here's the GitHub issue where they're tracking general custom attributes support: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/140

For now, `findDOMNode` seems to be the best workaround.

Comment: not very pretty, but you can always have two inputs, one with and one without, where you return the first if indeterminate state is true, and the other if its false..

Comment: This is how React works when you need to operate on dom nodes.

Comment: @Kyle The issue is that `indeterminate` is not even an attribute. It's a property.

Comment: React.findDOMNode is [deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#two-packages-react-and-react-dom). Use [this.refs.domref](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) instead.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest creating a simple component (code ported from coffeescript so mind you, might have some simple typos):

```
const React = require('react');

module.exports = class IndeterminateCheckbox extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.refs.box.indeterminate = this.props.indeterminate;
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if(prevProps.indeterminate !== this.props.indeterminate) {
            this.refs.box.indeterminate = this.props.indeterminate;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <input {...this.props} ref="box" type="checkbox"/>;
    }

}
```

Now you have a simple component that behaves exactly like a checkbox, that supports the `indeterminate` prop. Note there's plenty of room for improvements here, namely setting propTypes and proper defaults for some props, and of course implementing `componentShouldUpdate` to only do something when needed.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be to use a `ref` attribute with a callback to set the property on the DOM node. For example:

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <input
        type="checkbox"
        ref={function(input) {
          if (input != null) {
            React.findDOMNode(input).indeterminate = this.props.indeterminate;
          }}
        {...this.props} />
  )
}
```

Comment: Downvoting because with a `ref` you already have access to the DOM node. There is no need to do `React.findDOMNode(input)`.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use  React.findDOMNode(this).
It is risky.

```
export class SelectAll extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        checked: false
    };
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
}

onChange(e) {
    const checked = e.target.checked;
    this.setState({
        checked: checked
    });
    this.selectAllNode.indeterminate = false;
}

update(state: {
    checked: Boolean,
    indeterminate: Boolean
}) {
    this.setState({
        checked: state.checked
    });
    this.myRef.current.indeterminate = state.indeterminate;
}

render() {
    return ( <
        input type = "checkbox"
        name = "selectAll"
        checked = {
            this.state.checked
        }
        onChange = {
            this.onChange
        }
        ref = {
            this.myRef
        }
        />
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Can you help convert/implement this into react functional component?

Answer (score -1):

React v15 implementation:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Checkbox extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.el.indeterminate = this.props.indeterminate;
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if(prevProps.indeterminate !== this.props.indeterminate) {
            this.el.indeterminate = this.props.indeterminate;
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {indeterminate, ...attrs} = this.props;
        return <input ref={el => {this.el = el}} type="checkbox" {...attrs}/>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Taken from [my tutorial](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-checkbox-indeterminate) which shows how this works with the recent React features. I hope this helps someone who stumbles upon this older question:

```
const App = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(CHECKBOX_STATES.Empty);
 
  const handleChange = () => {
    let updatedChecked;
 
    if (checked === CHECKBOX_STATES.Checked) {
      updatedChecked = CHECKBOX_STATES.Empty;
    } else if (checked === CHECKBOX_STATES.Empty) {
      updatedChecked = CHECKBOX_STATES.Indeterminate;
    } else if (checked === CHECKBOX_STATES.Indeterminate) {
      updatedChecked = CHECKBOX_STATES.Checked;
    }
 
    setChecked(updatedChecked);
  };
 
  return (
    <div>
      <Checkbox
        label="Value"
        value={checked}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
 
      <p>Is checked? {checked}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const Checkbox = ({ label, value, onChange }) => {
  const checkboxRef = React.useRef();
 
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (value === CHECKBOX_STATES.Checked) {
      checkboxRef.current.checked = true;
      checkboxRef.current.indeterminate = false;
    } else if (value === CHECKBOX_STATES.Empty) {
      checkboxRef.current.checked = false;
      checkboxRef.current.indeterminate = false;
    } else if (value === CHECKBOX_STATES.Indeterminate) {
      checkboxRef.current.checked = false;
      checkboxRef.current.indeterminate = true;
    }
  }, [value]);
 
  return (
    <label>
      <input ref={checkboxRef} type="checkbox" onChange={onChange} />
      {label}
    </label>
  );
};
```