# Material UI Checkbox Indeterminate Attribute Doesn't Work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to show `indeterminate="true"` state in checkbox in Material UI:

```
<Checkbox
  label={obj.module}
  style={styles.checkbox}
  value={this.state.value}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not supported right now but i think it could be in the next set of releases going by this thread.

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/4828

in the meantime you can plug it in yourself with either by creating a component like here

[indeterminate checkbox in React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139455/indeterminate-checkbox-in-react-jsx)

and styling it yourself.